# Web scrape after search with Python, Selenium, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to web scrape a high school summary table after entering all the necessary information. However, I can't figure out how to do that since the url doesn't change after getting onto the school's page. I didn't find anything that is relevant to what I'm trying to do. Any idea how I can scrape a table after going through the search process? Thank you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("drivers/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")

state_drop = driver.find_element_by_id("state")
state = Select(state_drop)
state.select_by_visible_text(input("New Jersey"))

driver.find_element_by_id("city").send_keys(input("Galloway"))
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(input("Absegami High School"))
driver.find_element_by_class_name("forms_input_button").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element_by_id("hsSelectRadio_1").click()

url = driver.current_url
print(url)
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
school_info = soup.find('table', class_="border=")
print(school_info)
```

Comment: Which table do you want to scrape? As there are multiple tables available on the page.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the high school summary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")

state_drop = driver.find_element_by_id("state")
state = Select(state_drop)
state.select_by_visible_text("New Jersey")

driver.find_element_by_id("city").send_keys("Galloway")
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("Absegami High School")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("forms_input_button").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element_by_id("hsSelectRadio_1").click()

#scraping the caption of the tables
all_sub_head = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tableSubHeaderForWsrDetail") 

#scraping all the headers of the tables
all_headers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tableHeaderForWsrDetail")

#filtering the desired headers
required_headers = all_headers[5:]

#scraoing all the table data
all_contents = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tdTinyFontForWsrDetail")

#filtering the desired tabla data
required_contents = all_contents[45:]
    
print("                ",all_sub_head[1].text,"                ")
for i in range(15):
    print(required_headers[i].text, "              >     ", required_contents[i].text )
    
print("execution completed")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                 High School Summary                 
NCAA High School Code               >      310759
CEEB Code               >      310759
High School Name               >      ABSEGAMI HIGH SCHOOL
Address               >      201 S WRANGLEBORO RD
GALLOWAY
NJ - 08205
Primary Contact Name               >      BONNIE WADE
Primary Contact Phone               >      609-652-1485
Primary Contact Fax               >      609-404-9683
Primary Contact Email               >      bwade@gehrhsd.net
Secondary Contact Name               >      MR. DANIEL KERN
Secondary Contact Phone               >      6096521372
Secondary Contact Fax               >      6094049683
Secondary Contact Email               >      dkern@gehrhsd.net
School Website               >      http://www.gehrhsd.net/
Link to Online Course Catalog/Program of Studies               >      Not Available
Last Update of List of NCAA Courses               >      12-Feb-20
execution completed
```

**output screenshot: [click me!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zZ2O.png)**

Comment: use this `driver = webdriver.Chrome("drivers/chromedriver")`  instead of `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: can you explain ```required_contents = all_contents[45:]``` a little more?

Comment: as you can see there are three tables **High School Account Status**, **High School Summary*, **High School Information**, the common thing between these three tables are that the captions i.e in blue colour are stored under a common class `tableSubHeaderForWsrDetail`, and all the text with yellow background are stored in another common class `tableHeaderForWsrDetail`, also all the table data is stored in a common class `tdTinyFontForWsrDetail`

Comment: so `required_contents = all_contents[45:]` simply slices the table data i.e  5x9 = 45 table data blocks of table **High School Account Status** and stores the remaining table data blocks of the **High School Summary** in `required_contents` list